# Ansible / YML code needed to Reset / Power Cycle a VMware VM

Tags: ansible, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, ansible-playbook, yaml

I have a file called "vcenter.yml" in my hosts folder which is used to authenticate to my vcenter and perform a dynamic inventory of this vcenter.  I use this file to gather VM info and also to choe which Windows VM's I will be perfoming WINRM commands.  Also, I have a sample playbook called "vmware_list_all_powered-on_windows_vms.yml" that lists all powered on VMs within that vcenter.  So basically, I am able to type the command "ansible-playbook vmware_list_all_powered-on_windows_vms.yml" and the result will be a list of all powered on windows vm's.  The kicker is, I can also execute the same ansible command with the -l "A SPECIFIC VM NAME" and the result would be the powerstate of that SPECIFIC VM.  Now my problem, every google search I find pertaining to "how to power cycle a VM using ansible", it appears the vcenter name, vcenter credentials and specific vm name need to be in the playbook shown in the script "vm_reset.yml"

What would be the correct YML code to allow me to execute the command "ansible-playbook vm_reset.yml -l "A SPECIFIC VM NAME"?  I what to be able to utilize my existing "vcenter.yml" file for this purpose.

### VCENTER.YML

```
plugin: vmware_vm_inventory
strict: False
hostname: vcenter.foobar.com
username: fwhite@vsphere.local
validate_certs: False
with_tags: False
groups:
  VMs: True
  windowstest: "'win' in config.guestId"
  windows: "'win' in config.guestId"
filters:
- summary.runtime.powerState == "poweredOn"
hostnames:
- config.name
password: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
062353461393737393664396333653965383432363934316335306336326539393636653465616638386534303631633165636437326530303664306537300a646162303932326566373837643164643863373134333738326666376134333432633762653161333230643131363931613034343966373432396566393634660a6533623764653031386266353238383264336535626430626439656230386463
```

### VMWARE_LIST_ALL_POWERED-ON_WINDOWS_VMS.YML

```
- hosts: windows
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
  - name: Gather a list of all powered on VMs
    ansible.builtin.set_fact:
      on_vm: "{{ all_vm_info.virtual_machines | json_query(query) }}"
    vars:
      query: "[?power_state=='poweredOn']"
    register: jsoncontent

  - name: Gather a list of all powered on VM names
    debug: msg="{{ on_vm | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
    vars:
      jmesquery: "[*].{guest_name: guest_name, ip_address: ip_address}"
```

### VM_RESET.YML

```
---
- name: stop vm demo
  hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false
  collections:
    - community.vmware
  pre_tasks:
    - include_vars: vars.yml
  tasks:
    - name: guest shutdown
      vmware_guest_powerstate:
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        validate_certs: "{{ vcenter_validate_certs }}"
        name: "{{ vm_name }}"
        state: restarted
        state_change_timeout: 120
      register: deploy
      ignore_errors: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Is vm_name coming from vars.yml ?

If not you can pass it in using key=value format e.g.

```
ansible-playbook vm_reset.yml --extra-vars "vm_name=example"
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-at-runtime

You don't need vcenter.yml at all to pass in the name of the vm. If your goal was to dynamically execute it against a list of targets that are powered on I'd recommend assigning a host var or defining a group of powered on VMs (probably not the recommended method, but it may be easier than updating lines in an inventory file) such as power_state=='poweredOn' and then using that as the target for your playbook.

Comment: Hi philipenix:

That is the one file I left out.  You are correct, all the infomation below is being coming from a vars.yml file below:

VARS.YML

Comment: Hi philipenix:

I left out that file, sorry.  You are correct, all my vcenter credential information and VM NAME for the "vm_reset.yml" script is coming from the below vars.yml.  My goal is to do away with this vars.yml and use the vcenter.yml inventory file to obtain credentials and to be used by the "vm_reset.yml" playbook.  Then I can simply run
"ansible-playbook vm_reset.yml -l MYVM"

VARS.YML
------------
vcenter_hostname: "vcenter-test"
vcenter_datacenter: "VDC"
vcenter_validate_certs: false
vcenter_username: "fwhite@vsphere.local"
vcenter_password: "********"
vm_name: "MYVM"